# SQL Structure of DB table with different types of columns

Tags: php, sql, propel

I have a problem with the optimization of the structure of the database. I'll try to explain it exactly.

I create a project, where we can add different values​​, but this values must have different types of the columns in the database (eg, int, double , varchar). What is the best way to store the different types of values ​​in the database. In the project I'm using Propel 1.6. The point is availability to add value with 'int', 'varchar' and other columns types, to search the table was efficient.

In total, I have two ideas. The first is to create a table of "value", which will have columns: "id ", "value_int", "value_double", "value_varchar", etc - with the corresponding column types. Depending on the type of values​​, records will be saved with the value in the appropriate column (the rest will be NULL).

The second solution is to create separate tables such as "value_int", "value_varchar" etc. There would be columns: "id", "value", which correspond to the relevant types of "value" (ie, such as int, varchar, etc).

I must admit that I do not believe any of the above solutions, originally I was thinking about one table "value", where the column would be a "text" type - but this solution would probably be even worse.

I would like to know your opinion on this topic, maybe something else would be better. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
For example :

We have three tables:

USER: [table of users]
* id
* name

FIELD: [table of profile fields - where the column 'type' is the type of field, eg int or varchar)
* id
* type
* name

VALUE :
* id
* User_id - ( FK user.id )
* Field_id - ( FK field.id )
* value

So we have in each row an user in USER table, and the profile is stored in the VALUE table. Bit each profile field may have a different type (column 'type' in the FIELD table), and based on that I would want this value to add to the appropriate column of the appropriate type.

Comment: Doing it the _normaized_ way isn't an option?

Comment: @geomagas What do you mean with normalize? Database normalization?

Comment: Yep. Each value in a separate field with its type and all.

Comment: I think the issue here is explaining why you wish to do this. The solution _might_ be to set up a key-value store, using strings as the value and casting between types where you wish to store integers or floats. Or, if your purpose is to make a "customisable database" for your users, a table builder that creates a proper table might be better. But I think we need more background about what you are actually doing.

Comment: have a look on my question EDIT

Comment: I would go for the `separate tables` solution. It's normalized and therefor better.

Comment: +1 for `separate tables`. If you decently define your `schema.xml` with Propel you will have access between related objects, i.e. a key will have a pointer to the value and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

We used the first option and it works fine - that is having a column per type with another column that would specify the type.

PRO's:

- easy to read and filter (no joins, just a plain SELECT on the row)

CON's:

- the row takes more space

So if you would not need to superoptimize, I would go this way.

Another option could be to serialize the value somehow to an NVARCHAR(MAX) field (e.g. "TEXT: SampleText" or "INT: 8"). But that would make it not nicely database-searchable, e.g. for date or number ranges.